# Comparing two generic lists on a specific property

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, .net-2.0, list

I'm using VB.NET with .NET 2.0.

I have two lists, and I want to compare the lists on a specific property in the object, not the object as a whole, and create a new list that contains objects that are in one list, but not the other.

```
myList1.Add(New Customer(1,"John","Doe")
myList1.Add(New Customer(2,"Jane","Doe")

myList2.Add(New Customer(1,"","")
```

Result in the above example would contain one customer, **Jane Doe**, because the identifier `2` wasn't in the second list.

How can you compare these two `List<T>` or any `IEnumerable<T>` in .NET 2.0 (lacking LINQ)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the C# version, VB coming up shortly...

```
Dictionary<int, bool> idMap = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
myList2.ForEach(delegate(Customer c) { idMap[c.Id] = true; });

List<Customer> myList3 = myList1.FindAll(
    delegate(Customer c) { return !idMap.ContainsKey(c.Id); });
```

...and here's the VB translation. Note that VB doesn't have anonymous functions in .NET2, so using the `ForEach` and `FindAll` methods would be more clumsy than standard `For Each` loops:

```
Dim c As Customer

Dim idMap As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)
For Each c In myList2
    idMap.Item(c.Id) = True
Next

Dim myList3 As New List(Of Customer)
For Each c In myList1
    If Not idMap.ContainsKey(c.Id) Then
        myList3.Add(c)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in c# 2.0.

```
List<Customer> results = list1.FindAll(delegate(Customer customer)
                          {
                              return list2.Exists(delegate(Customer customer2)
                                               {
                                                   return customer.ID == customer2.ID;
                                               });
                          });
```

Comment: Is it possible with VB.NET (.NET 2.0)?

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my function to compare two list of objects:

Code:

```
Public Function CompareTwoLists(ByVal NewList As List(Of Object), ByVal OldList As List(Of Object))
            If NewList IsNot Nothing AndAlso OldList IsNot Nothing Then
                If NewList.Count <> OldList.Count Then
                    Return False
                End If
                For i As Integer = 0 To NewList.Count - 1
                    If Comparer.Equals(NewList(i), OldList(i)) = False Then
                        Return False
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            Return True
End Function
```

Example:

```
Dim NewList as new list (of string) from{"0","1","2","3"} 
Dim OldList as new list (of string) from{"0","1","2","3"} 
messagebox.show(CompareTwoLists(NewList,OldList)) 'return true 

Dim NewList as new list (of string) from{"0","1","2","4"} 
Dim OldList as new list (of string) from{"0","1","2","3"} 
messagebox.show(CompareTwoLists(NewList,OldList)) 'return false
```